# Images won't show on my website

Tags: html

I have a simple website. the address is: (removed for fear of hackers) It won't show images. i suppose you can use your browser's "view source" function, because stackoverflow treats my html code as formatting. it doesn't use any css (yet) but it simply won't show my images no matter what i do. what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Show us your code. You can indent it with four spaces so that it gets treated as source html.

Comment: SO won't treat your HTML as formatting if you click the code button in the editor's toolbar.

Comment: The reason is that permission is denied to the Images folder. Allow public access to that, and it will work. But you should have asked this on the webmasters forum.

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fomnyod.no-ip.org%2FOmnyOd%2FOmnyOd.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: Do you have an image in this path on your site, (from the root directory) `OmnyOd/Images/OmnyOd.png`

Answer (score 1):

You server reports:

> You don't have permission to access /OmnyOd/Images/OmnyOd.png on this server.

The problem is likely that your server doesn't have permission to read the files. Check the file permissions for them and the directory they are stored in. You can edit them with [chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod).

Answer (score 0):

You have a permissions problem in your web server.  When you try to access the images directly, you get a 403 Forbidden error.

Check that the permissions of the image files are set to be accessible to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanna use

```
<img src="/Images/Something.jpg" />
```

instead of

```
<img src="Images/Something.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the images folder permission to 755.

imagesfolder> chmod -R 755 .

Comment: Thanks! i figured that permissions wouldn't be a problem with Dreamweaver since they weren't with iWeb. Oh well thanks! and i'm gonna take off the URL for fear of hackers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check your virtual host configuration and the configuration of that folder in particular.

Some reference [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24068/virtualhost-and-403-forbidden-problem-with-apache).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your website is not configured to serve files with extension .png.
When I hit the image url directly (http://omnyod.no-ip.org/OmnyOd/Images/OmnyOd.png) I get 403 - Forbidden.